# Dropdown image menu not working in IE properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that that is suppose to switch the image of the button out with a darker image. I use HTML and CSS, and onmouseover/out JavaScript. My problem in IE is that the drop down part of the menu switches images at the top of the menu, however the image is suppose to drop down and stack below the main button. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I can not get to work in IE.

I was going to add a couple of pictures so you can see the result in IE and Chrome together, but I can't. I have try all that I can think of and have search online for the answer, but can't find it.

```
<div id="top_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/home.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/homeDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/home.png'" alt="Home" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/bigfour.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/bigfourDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/bigfour.png'" alt="Big Four" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/glucose.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/glucoseDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/glucose.png'" alt="Glucose" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/cholesterol.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/cholesterolDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/cholesterol.png'" alt="Cholesterol" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/bloodPressure.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/bloodpressureDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/bloodpressure.png'" alt="Blood Pressure" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/bmi.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/bmiDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/bmi.png'" alt="BMI" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/tobacco.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/tobaccoDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/tobacco.png'" alt="Tobacco" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/physicalActivity.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/physicalactivityDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/physicalactivity.png'" alt="Physical Activity" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/nutrition.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/nutritionDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/nutrition.png'" alt="Nutrition" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/wellnessChallenges.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/wellnesschallengesdark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/wellnesschallenges.png'" alt="Wellness Challenges" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="wellnessChampions.aspx">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/wellnessChampions.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/wellnesschampionsDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/wellnesschampions.png'" alt="Wellness Champions" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">
            <img src="Diversity%20Buttons%202/contact.png" onmouseover="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/contactDark.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Diversity%20Buttons%202/contact.png'" alt="Contact" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
enter code here
img
{
   border: none;
}

a
{
  outline: none;
}
#top_nav li:hover ul
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
#top_nav
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#top_nav li:hover ul
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
}

#top_nav
{
display: block;
position: relative;
}

#top_nav ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#top_nav li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#top_nav ul:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}


#top_nav ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px;

}
```

Comment: You could use sprites and just change the background-position on hover instead, would get rid of that small blip if the images aren't cached and the new source gets loaded

Comment: Could you show me how that code would work? I have never use sprites before.

Comment: Hello, here you'll find the [**Css Sprites**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) technique explanation.